# How to create Split-Flap Display using UITextView

Tags: ios, animation

Hi I am working on the task where i need to create the split-flap display similar to the this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYhlQDS03KM), most solutions I have found uses UIView but I want to use UItextView in my solution. Please help